# Install package in buildout environment

Tags: python, django, buildout, django-lfs

I'm using django-lfs that i installed it using buildout.
Now i need to install some other packages to my development environment.

My question is: What is the best way to install other packages (not system wide) in this kind of environment.
Say i want to install django-debug-toolbar only on my dev environment, but not in production.

I'm a user of virtualenv and pip

My project structure

```
myproject/
  README.txt  
  bootstrap.py  
  develop-eggs/  
  eggs/         
  misc/   
  scripts/
  bin/        
  buildout.cfg  
  dlcache/       
  lfs_project/  
  parts/  
  setup.cfg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add the packages to your buildout.cfg. Presumably there is a `eggs =` entry in that file, either at the global level (in the `[buildout]` section) or at the individual recipe level.

Adding extra lines is easy, it should end up looking something like this:

```
eggs = 
    django-lfs
    django-debug-toolbar
```

The egg names are white-space separated, new lines that are indented count as part of the initial line that is not (standard [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) format).

To differentiate between production and development configurations, simply create separate buildout configurations; I always use a `development.cfg` and a `production.cfg` (and `staging.cfg`, individual cluster machine .cfgs, etc). Buildout configurations can include and override other configurations, so your `development.cfg` could simply include `production.cfg` and add eggs and/or alter settings.

See the [buildout website](http://www.buildout.org/) for more information. If you want a complex example, look at the [Jarn Plone bootstrap buildout](https://github.com/Jarn/buildout); it uses separate `production.cfg` and `development.cfg` setups.

Comment: if you need to add some new package, it will only install that package?

Comment: If you update your buildout to add one new egg, running buildout again will add that egg to the local egg directory. The previously installed eggs will be left alone; those are already present after all. These eggs are not installed in the global site packages.